# Delete a row in Google Sheets with Java using the Google Sheets API

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api

I have an interface between my Java program and Google Sheets.
I want to delete a row in Google Sheets as soon as my condition is true.

Is there also a delete function? I haven't found anything in the documentation yet.

So far I have only found a function that clears the row.
This looks like this:

```
  ClearValuesRequest requestBody = new ClearValuesRequest();
  if (CALCNumber.toString().equals(BLNumber.get(0).toString())) {
       Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Clear request =
           sheets.spreadsheets().values().clear(spreadsheetId, "sheet1!A2:AA2", requestBody);       
       ClearValuesResponse deleteResponse = request.execute();
       System.out.print(deleteResponse);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#delete_a_row) when Google Change from `v3 API` to `v4 API` , the `Delete a row` request changes to `deleteDimension` using the method `spreadsheets.batchUpdate`.

The request body should have this structure:

*Note:  For example, the following removes the second row in `Sheet1`.*

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate

       {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "deleteDimension": {
                        "range":  {
                            "sheetId": 0,
                            "dimension": "ROWS",
                            "startIndex": 1,
                            "endIndex": 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
```

This is a sample on how the request should look like:

```
DeleteDimensionRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteDimensionRequest() 
   .setRange(
        new DimensionRange()
            .setSheetId(0)
            .setDimension("Row")
            .setStartIndex(1)
  );

List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
requests.add(new Request().setDeleteDimension(deleteRequest));

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);
sheetServices.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(SPREADSHEET_ID, body).execute()
```

**Reference:**

- [MigraDelete a row](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#delete_a_row)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate#deletedimensionrequest)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)
- [Delete rows or columns](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#delete_rows_or_columns)